# differentiation integral symbol

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I hopefully have a question which should be obvious to all but has been bothering me for sometime.

I have used the symbol $d$ for the differential entity of integration, for example, $$\int{x}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}x^2+c$$

Common to partial differential equations, I have typically used $d$ or $D$ to represent the total (or material or convective...) derivative as opposed to using $\partial$ to represent the partial derivative of a value.

My question is: why is $d$ still typically used when integrating partial differential equations, when in fact, I would argue that I am integrating with respect to a partial differential?

As an example, shouldn't $$\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}} \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} dx$$
be written as $$\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}} \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} \partial x$$
especially since I am only integrating over $x$?

Am I missing something, or is this just overlooked?

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: As an opinion (so I can't claim that what I'm going to say is true; it's only what I think) the reason integration uses the usual $dx$, not $\partial x$, is that there's no need to do otherwise. It doesn't matter where the integrand came from - it's still a function of two variables to be integrated. And if we're integrating with respect to $x$, then $dx=\Delta x$ as usually represents the infinitesimal change of $x$ as the independent variable, just as in the usual definition of "single" integrals.

Answer (score -3):

First, the derivative should always be written using an upright 'd' as in

$$ \int f(x) \mathrm{d}x $$

To address your question regarding the integration of a multivariable function, the integration can be seen as the integral with respect to each variable, just over a singleton bound.

$$ \int f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{x_0}^{x_1}\int_{y_0}^{y_0}f(x,y) \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x $$

So, are you doing a 'partial' integration? Not really. When you integrate only with respect to one variable, you're just integrating with respect to the second variable as well, but over an infinitesimal bound.

Comment: Minor notes: (1) $\mathrm{d}x$ is a differential, not a derivative. (2) Using upright $\mathrm{d}$ has been becoming more popular recently, but it most certainly not a rule, and $dx$ in integrals is just as good. But the really big deal is the "formula" you gave. That double, or rather repeated, integral that you gave **always evaluates to zero** and thus it is **NOT** equal to the original single integral. The statement "you're just integrating with respect to the second variable as well, but over an infinitesimal bound" doesn't really make sense. It actually is a partial integration.

Comment: Technical issues with the answer aside -- I'm partial to the upright d. How do you typeset that in MathJax?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Right-click on the formula and select “Show Math As > TeX Commands.”

Comment: @amd Awesome, thanks!